# grails 3.3 render JSON broken?

Tags: json, grails

We are trying to get a grails 2.5 project to work in grails 3.3

We have a json API, i.e. contolers which respond with JSON thusly:

```
            log.info("about to return json")
            render(status: 200, contentType: 'application/json') {
                [
                    'result': 9999,
                    'message': "hello"
                ]
            }
```

The problem is that the out put is always "{}".  This is the last code of the controller method.

If we do this:

```
 render("hello")
```

we get "hello".

If we do:

```
    render(status: 200, contentType: 'application/json') {
                    result = 0
                    player = "hello"
            }
```

We also always get "{{}" which seems crazy!

Any ideas? Is this broken in grails 3.3? This same code works perfectly in grails 2.5

Currently, the only solution we can find is to render the JSON by hand using string concatenation, which is tedious and error prone.

Answer (score 2):

Delving through the source code, it seems that grails 3 has changed the class responsible for JSON rendering under the hood to StreamingJsonBuilder. This has slightly different syntax, breaking existing 2.5 code.  Sadly, the render documentation and examples still have the "old" format.

There are two options:

1 use the new format, e.g:

```
render(status: 200, contentType: 'application/json') {
       result 0
       player "hello"
}
```

The disadvantage of this is that it doesnt work with custom Object Marshallers.

2 use the JSONBuilder, e.g.

```
def builder = new JSONBuilder()
def json = builder.build {
        result= "0"
        player= "hello"
 }
 render(status: 200, contentType: 'application/json', text: json)
```

This has two advantages: It works with Grails 2.5 and 3.x, so may work with grails 4.x.  Also, it works with Object Marshallers, which saves a lot of code.

A custom object marshaller looks like this:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##0.00");
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Account) {
        return [balance: df.format(it.balance), currencyIso: it.currencyIso, id: it.id]
    }
```

and you put them in your bootstrap.groovy (Which was moved from conf to init and given a different package in 3.x)

Comment: It is a shame the new format is not documented anywhere, can you provide the source link?

Comment: Relevant link to the documentation (section: JSON Builder Groovy Alignment) http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.0.RC2/guide/upgrading.html#